# How to copy tabs between frames in Aquamacs?

Tags: emacs, tabs, buffer, frame, aquamacs

I spend a lot of time coding in Aquamacs, and I tend to split the window into multiple frames. Each frame develops its own set of tabs at the top based on the history of what I've opened, and occasionally, I'll do something that (inadvertantly or not) closes a frame and causes me to lose all of the tabs at the top.

Is there a way to get the set of tabs to sync between two frames, or to have it always be the full set of active buffers? I don't think I want the set of tabs to be decoupled from the set of active buffers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with aquamacs itself, but given that it is basically a version of emacs for os x you could try to start Aquamacs as a daemon, and then just connect to it with `emacs-client` (`aquamacs-client`?), which will open up a frame.
If you open up 2 of such frames, you can effortlessly share your buffers between them.